# Oracle Change Notification, performance overhead?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Is there any performance overhead using Oracle Change Notification on a database table having fairly large size and on which 5k-8k operations are performed daily ?

After running it continuously for two days I have found few 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundException'

Comment: It should notify me, only on insert.
so i have set, 
prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_IGNORE_DELETEOP, "true");
        prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_IGNORE_UPDATEOP, "true");

Answer (score 0):

8k operations per day is trivial. My 10 year old laptop can do that. I suspect your java error is not performance/overhead related.

Comment: can you please provide me any web URL where I can understand more about different database change notification types